# c# razor, how to use html button to run a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I want to use the button to run a c# method how to do that? Now if i make a button with

```
<button type="button" onclick="@class.method()" >execute method</button>
```

it just executes that method on page load but doesnt do that on button click.

Comment: Use ajax to call server side function or use [Handler Methods in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using standard form or ajax form.

#### Option 1 - Standard form:

add `asp-page-handler` attribute to the button and specify the relevant method name, and on the back end create the relevant method with OnPost prefix.

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="button" asp-page-handler="RunMethod">execute method</button>
</form>
```

Backend method:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostRunMethod()
{
    //do whatever...
}
```

#### Option 2 - ajax form:

Use `data-ajax-url="?handler=RunMethod"` directly inside the form attributes or you can use a script to assign the relevant method handler to the form, with this approach you can use multiple buttons inside the same ajax form:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm"
        data-ajax="true"
        data-ajax-method="post"
        data-ajax-loading="#loading"
        data-ajax-failure="failed"
        data-ajax-update="#updateMsg">
    <button type="submit" id="RunMethod">execute method</button>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />

    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        failed = function (xhr) {
            alert('Status: {xhr.status}, Status text: {xhr.statusText}');
        }

        $("#RunMethod").on("click", function () {
            $("#myForm").attr("data-ajax-url", "?handler=RunMethod");
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Backend method:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostRunMethod()
{
    //do whatever...
}
```

see samples [here](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/MultipleSubmit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a handler method in the Razor page and use asp-page-handler attribute. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page) for more information.